# Null check operator used on a null value flutter firebase futurebuilder

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-futurebuilder

For some reason, i started getting this error
The app was running fine but now i don't know what is going and i don't know how to fix
I've tried refactoring the code to clear the error but at this point i need help

[image]

[image]

Comment: This error means you used Null check operator (`!`) on a value that is `Null`. From your screenshot, the only place you used `!` is on `currentUser`. Print it and confirm that it is not null.

Comment: Also, in your 3rd if statement. `if (snapshot.hasData)` is `true`, it means it has data and you should return the `SingleChildScrollView()`

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thank you this was the reason i was getting the error. I fixed it by checking if (snapshot.hastData == false) then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

As what I can interpret from the above stated problem is that , you are using Null check operator i.e `!` on a `Null` value.

From the above code , it is possibly from following line.

```
future: users.doc(currentUser!.uid).get
```

which means the `currentUser` is `Null`, Before building of the widget , try to print the value of currentUser.

And solution of the above problem is

- make sure `currentUser` is `not Null` before using `currentUser!.uid`
  or
- Try using `currentUser?.uid` which means that `uid` property will be accessed only if the `currentUser` is `not Null`

**Note**

- `currentUser!.uid` -> You are explicity telling the compiler `currentUser` is **never null** and to throw error if it's Null
- `currentUser?.uid` -> You will be able to access the `uid` property **only if** the `currentUser` is `not Null`.